# How to select a specific class - jQuery

Tags: jquery

Does anybody know how to select a specific class of an element. I have an element created in html. This element has two classes "n" and "s1" for example:

```
{<td class="n" class="s1" id=""><img src="gfx/football.png" /></td>}
```

Then in jquery I create another element (it's just a div). What I'm trying to do is: when the element above (td) is clicked I want to add same class (class s1) to my new `<div>`. I simply need these two elements with the same class.

The code I'm using looks like this:

```
myDIVishere.addClass($(this).attr('class')
```

This line adds a class to my new div but as you can see above my $(this) --> `<td>` has two classes. How to tell the program that I want to add second class (class="s1") and not the first one. I nearly forgot. I have 50 `<td>` elements so I can't use the class name.

Comment: Will it always be the second class? Or the last one? What if the element has only one class?

Comment: It should be `class="n s1"`. I'm not sure if your syntax is valid.

Comment: All elements will have two classes. Element 1 classes: p and s1, element 2 classes: p and s2, element 3 classes: n and s3 and so on. I want to select second class, not both or the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to fix your markup.

I tested in Opera and Chrome, and `class="foo" class="bar"` is not valid.

It should be `class="foo bar"`.

This considered, you can get the second class with the following:

```
var el = $('<a />', { class: 'foo bar' });
var classes = el.attr('class').split(' ');
var secondClass = classes[1];
```

Be sure to check secondClass for undefined before adding to another element, as this may lead to unexpected results.

Comment: ther's no class foo bar. But doesn't matter. That's what I needed. Two last lines. Thank you Andre.

Answer (score 0):

when you are using that attribute information to identify an element, you really should use an ID, that way its unique.

if you can't / won't store it in the ID attribute, instead store `s1` in a class, give it a separate and identifiable attribute... so you can grab it this way:

```
var specialValue = $('.myElement').attr('special-attribute');
$('.someOtherElement').addClass( specialValue );
```

but there, the use of `addClass` would also be a waste of energy. you can literally keep using attributes at that point.